# Converting VC++ project from VS2013 to VS2019 giving error is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2019

I had an old VC++ project on VS2013, now I have converted that project to VS2O19. It is able to create the dll successfully.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But that .dll not able to load in my web application. It is throwing below error.

Could not load file or assembly 'abc.xyz.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'abc.xyz.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
Filename: 'abc.xyz.dll'

Comment: I'm not sure there's much we can do to help here. Does it look like a valid .DLL? If you open a Developer Command prompt try `dumpbin /headers abc.xyz.dll` does it look correct? Does it look the same as a .DLL built by VS2013? Have you built it as 32-bits or 64-bits the same as before?

Comment: And you've tagged this both visual-c++ and .net. Is this C++, or .NET? Or is it both, C++/CLI? What's the program that you're trying to load it from?

Comment: @Rup It dumpbin /header it looks ok from my side. It has PE signature found, File Type: DLL, FILE HEADER VALUES 14C machine (x86), Executable, 32-bit word machine. Any specific key you want me to look.

Comment: @Rup It CLI C++ project which we are building in VS2019. Yes in VS2013 we are able to build as 32-bits and use this dll in ASP.net web project.

Comment: One surprising thing is in VS2019 build dll size 6/7 MB bigger compare to VS2013

Comment: "or one of its dependencies." You have the Visual C++ 2019 Runtime installed on the target machine and not just on your build machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joseph Willcoxson comments help. After installing Visual C++ 2019 runtime on the target machine this problem get resolve.